# Create a stacked density graph in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to create a stacked density graph in ggplot2, and I am also trying to understand how qplot works relative to ggplot.

I found the following example online:

```
qplot(depth, ..density.., data=diamonds, geom="density", 
  fill=cut, position="stack")
```

I tried translating this into a call to ggplot because I want to understand how it works:

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x=depth, y=..density..)) + 
  geom_density(aes(fill=cut, position="stack"))
```

This creates a density graph, but does **not** stack it.

What is the different between what qplot is creating and what ggplot is creating?

Here is a stacked density graph:

[image: stacked density]

Non-stacked density graph:

[image]

Original example is [here](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.2.1/stat_density.html)

Comment: `position="stack"` should be placed outside `aes`

Comment: My advice, if you're learning ggplot: ignore qplot. I find the syntax confusing, and while it can save you some keystrokes it will cost you more in heartbreak.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From @kohske's comment, the position is not an aesthetic, and so should not be inside the `aes` call:

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x=depth, y=..density..)) + 
  geom_density(aes(fill=cut), position="stack")
```

[image]

or using the movies data (which your example graphs use):

```
ggplot(movies, aes(x=rating, y=..density..)) + 
  geom_density(aes(fill=mpaa), position="stack")
```

[image]