# ggplot2 doesn't recognise values from molten data

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, reshape2

I'm trying to make a simple stacked density plot following the example here: [Create a stacked density graph in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12980081/create-a-stacked-density-graph-in-ggplot2).

I'm using melted data, but when I try to plot it with "value" on the y-axis, I get an error.

Here's my original data:

```
> str(bug)
'data.frame':   39 obs. of  10 variables:
 $ year           : int  2006 2006 2006 2006 2006 2006 2006 2006 2006 2006 ...
 $ SampleDate     : Factor w/ 39 levels "01-Aug-07","02-Jun-06",..: 21 32 2 11 19 28 37 8 17 24 ...
 $ Oligochaeta    : int  905 604 371 991 213 144 1 14 5 5 ...
 $ Copepoda       : int  586 352 12 602 45 24 3 1 1 8 ...
 etc.
```

And this is how I used melt:

```
> mbug <- melt(bug, id.vars=c("year", "SampleDate"))
```

I corrected the date format:

```
> mbug$date1 <- as.Date(mbug$SampleDate, "%d-%b-%y")
```

And this the molten data:

```
> str(mbug)
'data.frame':   312 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ year      : int  2006 2006 2006 2006 2006 2006 2006 2006 2006 2006 ...
 $ SampleDate: Factor w/ 39 levels "01-Aug-07","02-Jun-06",..: 21 32 2 11 19 28 37 8 17 24 ...
 $ variable  : Factor w/ 8 levels "Oligochaeta",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ value     : int  905 604 371 991 213 144 1 14 5 5 ...
 $ date1     : Date, format: "2006-05-18" "2006-05-26" "2006-06-02" "2006-06-09" ...
```

I used ggplot with the molten data:

```
> ggplot(mbug, aes(x=date1, y=value)) +
+ geom_density(aes(fill=variable), position="stack")
+ facet_wrap(~ year, nrow=1) + theme(text = element_text(size = 22))
```

And ended up with this error:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'y' not found
```

Ultimately, I'd like the variable to be called "taxon" and the value to be called "abundance", but I can always do that in ggplot later. Right now, my main goal is being able to plot y!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Change `aes(x=date1, y=value)` to `aes(value)` (or `aes(x=value)`). A density plot is a smoothed histogram giving the distribution of a single variable. Density is plotted on the y axis, and that's calculated internally by ggplot.

Comment: To duplicate this error with a built-in data frame: `ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg, fill=factor(cyl))) + geom_density()`. To get the desired plot:
`ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg, fill=factor(cyl))) + geom_density()`.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like maybe what you want is not a density plot but an area plot of `value` vs. `date1`. Maybe something like this, but hard to be sure without being able to work with a sample of your data:

```
ggplot(mbug, aes(x=date1, y=value, fill=variable)) +
    geom_area() +
    facet_wrap(~ year, nrow=1) + 
    theme(text = element_text(size = 22))
```

For comparison, here's an example with fake data:

```
set.seed(984)
dat = data.frame(time=rep(1980:2020,2), 
                 value=c(cumsum(rnorm(41,10,20)),cumsum(rnorm(41,10,20))),
                 group=rep(c("A","B"), each=41))

ggplot(dat, aes(time, value, fill=group)) + 
  geom_area() +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

A density plot is a smoothed histogram giving the distribution of a single variable. Density is plotted on the y axis, and that's calculated internally by ggplot. For example, if I wanted the distribution of vehicle fuel economy (that is, the fraction of cars within each fuel economy interval), I could do this:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg)) + geom_density()
```

But if I do the following, it causes the same error you're getting:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg) + geom_density()
```

This is because the "y" value in a density plot is the density (height on the y axis) of the x variable at each value of x.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, this has worked, with only one more tweak to make it perfect. Using `facet_wrap`, I have one panel for each year. But within that panel, it plots the entire date range. I only want May to August for each year. This is part of the reason that I corrected the date format... With `geom_line`, I was able to define `group=year`. Is there an equivalent in `geom_area`?

Comment: Never mind, I worked it out: `ggplot(mbug, aes(x=date1, y=value, fill=variable)) +
  geom_area(stat="identity") +
  facet_wrap(~ year, nrow=1, scales="free_x") + 
  theme(text = element_text(size = 22))` Thank you again for your clear and concise answer!